# problem with aligning fixed

Tags: css

How can i make a fixed div stick with the container div on the left side on all screen resolutions?

```
#container{
    background-color:#000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity: 0.85; 
    opacity: 0.85; 
    width:1000px;
    min-height:1275px;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
}

#fixed{
    position: fixed; 
    top:150px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is kinda impossible with the css property fixed, but what u could do is position the container div relative the position the fixed div absolute then simulate the fixed effect with Jquery.
example

## container{

```
background-color:#000;
filter:alpha(opacity=85); 
-moz-opacity: 0.85; 
opacity: 0.85; 
width:1000px;
min-height:1275px;
height:100%;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
}
```

## fixed{

```
width:100px;
position:absolute; 
top:150px;
left:-100px;
```

}

the jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $scrollingDiv = $("#fixed");            
    $(window).scroll(function(){            
    $scrollingDiv
    .stop()
    .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, "slow" );           
    });
    });

Comment: We added another div with fixed position inside the #fixed div and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you correctly. Maybe this will work:

```
#container{
    background-color:#000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity: 0.85; 
    opacity: 0.85; 
    width:1000px;
    min-height:1275px;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;

    position:relative;
}

#fixed{
    position: absolute; 
    top:150px; 
}
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/gQP8X/2/ **Note**: I've made some changes to better jsfiddle conformance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 #wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;

 }

 #content{
    margin: auto;
    width: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
 }

 #sidebar{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
        left: -100px;
 }

 #fixed{
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: cyan;
 }
```

And

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="fixed">something</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```